# Advanced Tiling Problem (From Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

Show that a 444-by-77 chessboard can be completely tiled by 1-by-6 pieces
but a 44-by-777 chessboard cannot.

I have an example and can follow this for when the chessboard is a square, say 10-by-10 but don't know how to do it for a board with uneven side lengths.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  The usual approach for proving something can be tiled is to show a tiling.  In this case $6$ divides $444$, so you should be able to find one.

A common approach to proving something cannot be tiled is to find a way to color the squares so that every place you put a tile covers the same number of squares of each color.  As your tiles are six squares, this suggests a coloring with six colors.  Can you find a regular way to color the squares so that anywhere you put a tile covers one square of each color?  Then if you color a $44 \times 777$ board that way and there are different numbers of squares colored some colors, the board cannot be covered.  An example would be proving you cannot take an $8 \times 8$ chessboard, remove diagonally opposite corners, and cover the remaining area with $31$ dominoes.  Using the usual coloring, you have $30$ squares of one color and $32$ of the other, while each domino covers one of each, so there will be two left over.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I think I got it

Comment: Then you can write up the full answer.  The FAQ encourages you to answer your own question if you figure out how.  After some delay, you will be able to accept your answer by clicking the check mark beside it.